# Cross product of vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have written the following function to calculate travel distance between two locations.

```
# Get Distance
require(RJSONIO)
address1 = "Noida Sector 62"
address2 = "Connaught Place"
url <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
url <- URLencode(paste(url, "origins=", address1,"&", "destinations=", address2, "&sensor=false", "&units=metric", "&mode=driving",  sep = ""))
x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
metres = x$rows[[1]]$elements[[1]]$distance$text
```

I want to make the above program run for all the possible combinations of the locations mentioned in the vector below -

```
address = c("Noida Sector 62" , "Saket", "Delhi University, North Campus", "Laxmi Nagar", "Khan Market", "Connaught Place")
```

Comment: Can `address1` be equal to `address2`?

Comment: You can look at `?combn` or (if you want to consider address1 == address2) `?outer`.

Comment: No, it can't be same

Comment: There is no function here. You've just written a script. You can abstract this out into a function easily. Check out this article for references https://nicercode.github.io/guides/functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `expand.grid` to get all combinations of addresses.

```
distance <- function(a1, a2){
    url <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
    url <- URLencode(paste(url, "origins=", a1,"&", "destinations=", a2, "&sensor=false", "&units=metric", "&mode=driving",  sep = ""))
    x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
    metres <- x$rows[[1]]$elements[[1]]$distance$text
    metres
}

address = c("Noida Sector 62" , "Saket", "Delhi University, North Campus", "Laxmi Nagar", "Khan Market", "Connaught Place")

add <- expand.grid(A1 = address, A2 = address, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
add <- add[add$A1 != add$A2, ]
row.names(add) <- NULL
d <- apply(add, 1, function(x) distance(x[1], x[2]))
d
#[1] "29.0 km" "24.0 km" "10.7 km" "18.1 km" "18.3 km" "27.3 km" "27.0 km"
# [8] "18.6 km" "11.1 km" "15.8 km" "28.2 km" "28.3 km" "15.3 km" "16.8 km"
#[15] "8.5 km"  "11.3 km" "20.2 km" "15.3 km" "8.8 km"  "7.4 km"  "18.8 km"
#[22] "10.9 km" "17.7 km" "8.3 km"  "5.5 km"  "19.5 km" "14.0 km" "9.4 km" 
#[29] "7.1 km"  "4.7 km"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`combn`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.1/topics/combn) to create all possible combinations of addresses (here we use `m = 2` as we want combinations of two). Then use loop to iterate over the pairs (`foo` matrix).

```
require(RJSONIO)
api <- "API_SEQUENCE"

address <- c("Noida Sector 62" , "Saket", "Delhi University, North Campus", "Laxmi Nagar", "Khan Market", "Connaught Place")

foo <- combn(address, 2)
metres <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(foo)) {
    address1 <- foo[1, i]
    address2 <- foo[2, i]
    url <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"   
    url <- URLencode(paste(url, "origins=", address1,"&", "destinations=", address2, "&sensor=false", "&units=metric", "&mode=driving",  sep = ""))
    x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
    metres[[i]] <- x$rows[[1]]$elements[[1]]$distance$text
}

foo[, 1:5]
     [,1]              [,2]                             [,3]             
[1,] "Noida Sector 62" "Noida Sector 62"                "Noida Sector 62"
[2,] "Saket"           "Delhi University, North Campus" "Laxmi Nagar"    
     [,4]              [,5]             
[1,] "Noida Sector 62" "Noida Sector 62"
[2,] "Khan Market"     "Connaught Place"
```

Comment: Why `foo[, i][1]` and not `foo[1, i]`?

Comment: url  needs to be inside for-loop otherwise link of previous iteration gets used. Also it does not returns metres for all combinations

Comment: @John Changed loop output: it appends to list `meters` for each iteration

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas for your help. Highly appreciated! Could you please show the combinations for which metres are calculated? In the list meters, it shows only meter values. Would you mind removing my API from answer?